# How many ordered pairs $(A,B)$ they are if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ such that $A \cap B = \{1\}$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ordered pairs $(A,B)$ they are if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\{ 1,2,3,4,5 \}$ such that $A \cap B = \{1\}$?

If 1 is in both sets :

Size of $A$ is $>1$ and size of $B$ is $>1$.

$\Rightarrow$ Size of $A \cup B =4$

$$5 \cdot (3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3) = 405$$ is not correct.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, think about $A\setminus\{1\}$ and $B\setminus\{1\}$. Clearly, there is an obvious one-one correspondence between every possible instance of $(A,B)$ and $(A\setminus\{1\},B\setminus\{1\})$, and $A\setminus\{1\}\cap B\setminus\{1\}=\varnothing$.

Comment: How do you get "Size of $A$ is $\gt1$"?

Comment: I should add : >= 1

Answer (score 10):

Each of the elements $2, 3, 4, 5$ can be in $A, B$, or neither.  These possibilities are mutually exclusive and exhaustive.  So the number of possible ordered pairs of subsets that work is $3^4=81$.

Comment: Thank you  - so I was multiplying by 5 for no reason - thats what I missed :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  When you have enough reputation to do so, acceptances of answers you find useful are always appreciated.